# How to print raw html data in angularjs template using mvc

Tags: angularjs

I have a angularjs project where data come from database.
and bind in html template.
some data inserted from text editor, and i need to show the data in html template like @html.raw in mvc.
is it possible.

Comment: Include [angular-sanitize](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize) and bind like this: `<p ng-bind-html="myHtmlVariable"></p>`

Comment: when i am using          $scope.item = '<p style="color:black;">I am an <code>HTML</code>string with ' +
       //'<a href="#">links!</a> and other <em>stuff</em></p>';   it work .And when $scope.item bind from database not working.

Comment: That's why I said to use the `angular-sanitize` library, that's what it partially is made for

Comment: Does user specifically insert HTML code via text editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use

```
<div class="blog-main-descripton" ng-repeat="d in Htmlrow">
            <p ng-bind-html="d.value"></p>
        </div>
```

and my code is runing

Answer (score 1):

Check out the angular-sanitize module.
I've created a plunk to demonstrate how it works: [Check this plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/Qpohxo)

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="testController">
    <div ng-bind-html="customHtmlContent">
    </div>
</body>

angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize']).controller('testController',
    function($scope, $sanitize){
        $scope.customHtmlContent = $sanitize('<strong>Lorem ipsum dolor</strong>');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

angular sanitize is a good option as I have used it into my project.